# Bootstrap custom widths on IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I love using bootstrap, but sometimes the widths of the spans don't do it for me, and I need to create custom divs with custom widths ( i.e if I don't like the gutters, or need to have 5 spans etc.

The way I do it is by defining a width, than going to each media query, and defining a different width there.

When I visit in IE, however, bootstrap defaults to a 1024width, and my custom divs don't adjust.

Here's an example --

http://dentasignclients.com/sawyer

In the body there are 3 columns of the doctor's picture, and it drops down in IE

My question is, how do I define the width of custom divs, for when someone is viewing it in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media-queries in IE are only supported in IE9 or greater so that is why you are not seeing it adjust as you expect.  [Can I use CSS3 Media Queries](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries)

You will have to add a third party  library like [css3-mediaqueries-js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) to get it to work with older IE browsers.